# Simple Form: creating a new record from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for

I have a Home controller with an index view that acts like a search box that lets the user query a First Table or Second Table through a select box. After a user enters a search term, he will be redirected to the index page of the First or Second model with the search results for that model.

A Search record must be created each time a query is submitted with the search type and search term. However, I don't know how to create a new Search object using simple_form from a different controller, which is the Home controller in this case.

Home Controller

```
def index
  @find = Find.new
```

Home Index View

```
= simple_form_for @find, url: finds_path, method: :post do |f|
  = f.input :search_type, :collection => [['First', 'First'], ['Second', 'Second']]
  = f.input :search_term
  = f.button :submit
```

Finds Controller

```
def new
  @find = Find.new
end

def create
  @find = Find.new(find_params)
  if params[:search_type] == 'First'
    redirect_to first_path
  elsif params[:search_type] == 'Second'
    redirect_to second_path
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

private

def find_params
  params.permit(:search_term, :search_type, :utf8, :authenticity_token, 
    :find, :commit, :locale)
  # the params seem to come from the Home controller so I added them just to see if they will go through :(
end
```

It doesn't save. Instead it gives:

```
Started POST "/en/finds"
Processing by FindsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"..", "find"=>{"search_type"=>"First", "search_term"=>"Something"}, "commit"=>"Create Find", "locale"=>"en"}
Unpermitted parameter: :find
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/en
```

Comment: Post your full `finds_cntroller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unpermitted parameter: :find

Your `find_params` should be just

```
def find_params
  params.require(:find).permit(:search_type, :search_term)
end
```

You should access the `search_type` with `params[:find][:search_type]`

```
if params[:find][:search_type] == 'First'
  redirect_to first_path
elsif params[:find][:search_type] == 'Second'
  redirect_to second_path
  else
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Also, I would suggest renaming the `Find` model as it conflicts with [`ActiveRecord#FinderMethods`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find)

Comment: Would 'Search' be a better name for the table of queries?

Comment: @JunDalisay It could be a better name but be careful when you are using any gems for implementing search. Most of the gems uses `search` as a method name

Answer (score 0):

You need to save, you are just initializing the attributes..

```
@find = Find.new(find_params)
@find.save!
```

OR

```
@find = Find.create!(find_params)
```

Also, strong parameters should be

```
def find_params
  params.require(:find).permit(:search_term, :search_type)
end
```